# Help assigning Gridview check box to a variable

Tags: vb.net

This line of code references a checkbox in a Gridview, how can I assign the value of the check box 1 or -1, I think it is for checked or unchecked, to a variable so that I can run an if statement against it, and change it to True or False?

```
dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("DisplayString") = (CType((row.Cells(3).Controls(0)), CheckBox)).Checked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim checkBox1 as CheckBox = CType((row.Cells(3).Controls(0)), CheckBox)
checkBox1.Checked = True
```

---

**Edit**

I'm not sure I completely understand what it is you are trying to do?

Are are you are attempting to check/uncheck the CheckBox based on the values 1 or -1?

Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me. I need to read the condition/status of the check box and use an if statement on the result....

```
dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("DisplayString") = (CType((row.Cells(1).Controls(0)), CheckBox)).Checked

Dim CB As CheckBox = CType((row.Cells(1).Controls(0)), CheckBox)
value = CB.Checked
```

Now I can use 'value' in my if statements.